How can I improve xgboost classifier if overfitting start from the initial epochs?
I am training a XGBoost multi-class classifier, but got very bad result. The train/val leaning multi-class logloss curve showed that overfitting started from the early epochs. What directions can I improve the model?

Firstly, are you using cross-validation (or some suitable alternative for your particular situation, e.g. time series problems might needs things like rolling windows)? If you are relying on a single train/validation split on a small dataset your diagnosis of there being overfitting might at least be debatable (although you should most definitely be concerned about it and even more so in small datasets).
If you are using a high a learning rate (the default for eta aka learning_rate of 0.3 is pretty high), one way to slow down how long it takes until the same extent of overfitting occurs is to use a lower learning rate (what are you using? you could go e.g. as low as 0.005). A low enough value should given a decent amount of data eventually result in at least the initial predictions not being overfitted (because the the learning rate in a sense controls how much each new tree created is allowed to make the prediction deviate from the default average prediction).
Additionally, there's various other penalization parameters that you can use to reduce overfitting. You'll likely want to use those in addition to controlling the learning rate, because with enough iterations you'd get similar overfitting even with a lower learning_rate and with properly tuned penalization you can for any given learning rate usually get better performance than without (the optimal other parameters will not be exactly the same for different learning rates). In contrast, it is usually the case that a lower learning rate is better or at least no worse than a higher one once everything else is chosen optimally (you just need more iterations leading to a performance vs. training-/inference-time trade-off).
E.g. a lower tree-depth (make it lower than default of 6 for max_depth), a higher amount of observation that need to be present for splitting to be permitted (controlled e.g. by min_child_weight), subsampling observations (default is 1 = 100% of samples, make it lower e.g. 0.7) or features (default colsample_bytree=1 = 100% of features, could make it lower e.g. 0.7) for trees, L1-penalty (alpha) and L2-penalty (lambda)  - to name some of the most commonly used ones. Setting these towards heavier penalization ought to help.
